# Не выводится alert

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код:

```
for(u=0; u<arr2.length; u+=2){
    if(arr2[u+1]!=arr2[u+3]){
test++;
    }
}

if(test==0){
    alert("Хотя бы один символ должен повторяться больше, чем "+arr2[1]+" раз");
    stop();
}
```

arr2 равняется символ,число,символ,число,символ,число. Пример: d,1,e,1,h,1,q,1

суть такова: Если числа везде одинаковы, то скрипт останавливается, выводя текст через alert - "Хотя бы один символ должен повторяться больше, чем "число" раз"

Подскажите, почему не выводится алерт

Comment: Так у вас в примере числа не равны и в цикле счетчик увеличивается, соответственно, test не равно 0.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что у вас не так. Запустил ваш код, в результате test стал равен 4, поэтому у вас не вызывается алерт. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам подсказали, где у вас ошибка. То добавьте больше описания, какие входные данные должны быть, чтобы test был равен 0, и что должно быть, чтобы test не был равен 0.

Comment: Немного исправил. В данной ситуации числа равны

Comment: Повторюсь: Если все числа из arr2 после символов повторяются, то появляется алерт с надписью, а после скрипт завершается. Ничего сложного

Comment: "Вот код и пример данных. На пример не обращайте внимания." - я лучше не буду обращать внимания на этот вопрос: -1.

Comment: Это пример данных, а не данные. Пример - это то, какими они могут быть, а не то, какими являются

Comment: Вам на философский факультет. А мне - на филологический.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда обращаетесь к элементу массива в arr2[u+3], проверяйте не вышли ли вы за границы массива. У вас в конце цикла arr2[u+3] будет undefined, поэтому счетчик срабатывает.